# Create regex pattern

Tags: regex, html

I want to create a regex for this pattern 999-999-9999, please advise.

```
<input type='tel' pattern='/^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/' title='Phone Number (Format: 999-999-9999)' />
```

Answer (score 1):

You nearly had it. Here's a simple one.

It goes: 3 digits, hyphen, 3 digits, hyphen, 4 digits. But that's pretty self explanatory.

`\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}`